# Unable to change name value in a vector

Tags: r

1. `named_vector=c(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7)`
2. `names(named_vector)[names(named_vector)=='c'] <- 'k'`
3. `names(named_vector[names(named_vector)])=='c'<-'k'`

Unable to change name of a member 'c' in named_vector using line 3, but working fine with line 2
getting the error message as --------------------->

Error in names(named_vector[names(named_vector)]) == "c" <- "k" :
could not find function "==<-"

Comment: Also possible: `names(named_vector)[which(names(named_vector)=="c")] <- 'k'`

Answer (score 1):

You can index by numeric position:

```
`names(named_vector)[3] <- "new name" `
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 doesn't work because you're nesting your data too much. If you break this down

```
names(named_vector[names(named_vector)]) == 'c' <- 'k'
```

you get

```
# Gives you all the names back
names(named_vector)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"

# Putting it back in, you simply get all the values again
names(named_vector[c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")])

# The inner part simply gives you the `named_vector` again
named_vector[c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")]
# a b c d e f g 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

This is not to mention that the assignment is being saved into a vector

```
names(named_vector[names(named_vector)]) == 'c'
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So Line 2 works because you're indexing your vector names by the equality of which label you wish you change.

```
names(named_vector)[names(named_vector) == 'c'] <- 'K'
```